# ICS subscription feed working on Apple Calendar but not working on Google Calendar:

Tags: express, google-calendar-api, icalendar

**EDIT : Solved. See below.**

This subscription feed is working on Apple Calendar but not working on Google Agenda:

While importing the ics file directly: the error "Unable to process your iCal/CSV file." comes out.

While subscribing to the URL: no events are showing in the calendar but no errors are displayed.

URL: `https://app.lamainverte.ca/ical/mon-potager-2897.ics`

This exact URL is also validated by https://icalendar.org/validator.html

This is the structure for the first few events:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:adamgibbons/ics
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Mon potager
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:CKoZRMVRnOmBI--uSQ13r
SUMMARY:Fertilisation - Oseille
DTSTAMP:20240131T155944Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20240120
URL:https://app.lamainverte.ca/calendrier
CATEGORIES:Potager
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
DURATION:P1DT
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:YTMi2gRyn7F_0zJNGFQYQ
SUMMARY:Semis intérieur - Oseille
DTSTAMP:20240131T155944Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20240412
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20240517
URL:https://app.lamainverte.ca/calendrier
CATEGORIES:Potager
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:Tz9Ua5mZnt_NTcFL5gy_4
SUMMARY:Acclimation - Oseille
DTSTAMP:20240131T155944Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20240517
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20240527
URL:https://app.lamainverte.ca/calendrier
CATEGORIES:Potager
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
```

How it's generated:

```
function presentTaskIntoIcalEvent(task: any) {
  let icalEvent: any = {
    title: task.name,
    start: convertDateToIcalFormat(task.startDate),
    url: task.url,
    categories: ['Potager'],
    calName: 'Mon potager',
    transp: 'TRANSPARENT',
  }
  if (task.endDate) {
    icalEvent['end'] = convertDateToIcalFormat(task.endDate)
  } else {
    icalEvent['duration'] = { days: 1 }
  }
  return icalEvent
}
```

And the array of events is sent to the feed with:

```
icalRouter.get('/ical/:selectionSlug.ics', async (request, response) => {
    const events = getAllEvents()
    ics.createEvents(events)
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/calendar')
    response.send(icalFeed)
})
```

Any help would be appreciated. I didn't find any Google-specific fields in the [ics npm package documentation](https://github.com/adamgibbons/ics).

Comment: Can edit your question to include a bit more specificity about what *exactly* is "*not working*"? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? What errors in the interface or associated developer console are you seeing, if any?

Comment: I deleted one event at the time till it works. The field GEO: had undefined values. Literally GEO:undefined;undefined; Google isn't tolerating that while Apple is.